# Подсчет количества значений по каждому признаку

Tags: php, mysql

Существует следующий алгоритм:

```
$bd = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list GROUP BY class");
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($bd))
{
    $res = $myrow['class'];
    $lec = 0; $sem = 0; $lab = 0;
    $bd2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list WHERE class='$res'");
    while ($myrow2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($bd2))
    {

        $type = $myrow2['type']; 
        if($type == 'Лекция') {
            $lec = $lec + $myrow2['count_hours'];
            echo $lec.' часов ';
        }

        if($type == 'Семинар') {
            $sem = $sem + $myrow2['count_hours'];
            echo $sem.' часов ';
        }

         if($type == 'Лабораторная') {
            $lab = $lab + $myrow2['count_hours'];
            echo $lab.' часов ';
        }
        echo $res = $myrow2['class'].' ';
        echo $type = $myrow2['type'].' ';
        echo $rest = $myrow2['discipline']."<br>";

    }
}
```

Он подсчитывает суммирует часы по всем предметам одной группы. А как сделать так, чтобы он суммировал часы по каждому предмету каждой группы? Предметы получается нужно как то разделить. Как то реализовать через if else? Поместить блок с расчетом в оператор if else, и чтоб он проверял старое значение с новым. В случае если предметы не совпадают, то обнулять переменные и делать подсчет заново. Как так на практике реализовать....

***Результат работы алгоритма:***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P.S. Через агрегатные функции реализовать не получается.**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/726d9/4/0

Comment: Структуру таблицы мы сами должны придумать?

Comment: Р-р-р... Результат `show create table` где?

Comment: Шамиль, ты фактически одну и ту же тему здесь закидываешь уже много раз. Но не понимаешь ответов. Может начнешь читать документацию и разбираться, повышать свой уровень? 
Есть мега-полезный сервис sqlfiddle.com. Создай там "песочницу" с рабочими данными чтобы всякий добрый человек мог попробовать твои данные вживую. Вот увидишь — полезная отдача будет.

Comment: Спасибо большое, не знал про такой сервис. Создал так как Вы посоветовали: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/726d9/4/0

Comment: Прекрасно! Точно так же можно сгруппировать и просуммировать по любому сочетанию полей. Например: класс + тип занятий http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/726d9/11 Аналогично группа + дисциплина или что угодно! **Важно** чтобы во фразе SELECT не было случайных полей. Допустимы поля из списка group by + агрегатные функции. Всё остальное ложь и провокация.

Comment: Замечательно. А как мне можно объединить записи? Для групп ПМ11 и ПМ12 - должно быть подсчитано общее количество лекций, семинаров, и лабораторных. Запрос должен это как то понимать. Я так полагаю здесь применим оператор LIKE?

Comment: Не уверен что понимаю. Надо все группы считать отдельно, а одну пару объединить? Лучше бы у них было какое-то общее поле по которому можно группировать, но в принципе группировка по **под-строке** тоже возможна. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/726d9/29

Comment: Видите, сейчас запрос считает общее количество часов по всем предметам каждой группы. А мне нужно чтоб считал общее количество часов, по каждому предмету каждой группы. Т.е для Информатики отдельно считал(кол. лекций, семинаров, лабораторных), для проектирования отдельно считал (кол. часов лекций, семинаров, лабораторных) и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

С данным "алгоритмом" работать в принципе нельзя.
Поскольку из всех сгруппированных строк он будет возвращать только одну, причем случайную.

При использовании `GROUP BY` вычисления надо производить в самом запросе, и выбирать только те поля, которые при группировке являются уникальными. То есть, запрос вида `SELECT * FROM ... GROUP BY` в принципе не имеет смысла. Тогда уж лучше возвращайся к своему полному перебору таблицы - это будет хоть и криво, но хотя бы данные будут верны.

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста на примере, как мне произвести все эти вычисления в запросе, чтоб он подсчитывал часы по каждому предмету, каждой группы.

Comment: @Шамиль Асланов, без понимания тебе никакие примеры не помогут. Вот описание группировок по русски, может поможет: http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_group_by_clause.html От себя добавлю, что НЕЛЬЗЯ использовать вывод всех полей по * когда группируешь. Потому что нельзя никогда. Просто запомни это, а поймешь потом.